# CSS spinning wheel stop after 5 seconds?

Tags: css

I am using this CSS code I found on fiddle to spin my wheel:

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9Ryvs/7/

```
div {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Basically I want to stop the spinning exactly after it reaches 1800 Degress, and then go back to 0 so I can spin it again later.

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the `animation-iteration-count` appropriately.

1800 degrees = 5 full rotations (5 * 360)

```
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:5;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:5;
-ms-animation-iteration-count:5;
-o-animation-iteration-count:5;
animation-iteration-count:5;
```

It should automatically reset to 0 upon completion.

[This documentation might give some more context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count).

**EDIT**

[Updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ryvs/81/). Side note, you should consider including `-o-animation` items in there as well, in case they have Opera v12. Also, consider shorthand.

```
-webkit-animation:spin 4000ms linear 0s 5;
-moz-animation:spin 4000ms linear 0s 5;
-ms-animation:spin 4000ms linear 0s 5;
-o-animation:spin 4000ms linear 0s 5;
animation:spin 4000ms linear 0s 5;
```

Comment: Spin is running on 555ms per 360 degress (Not sure, please see the fiddle or the code). On the code, it is 4000ms, but change it to 555ms. I want to make a javascript timeout, so it will change the img to a not moving one. how much ms in total? (555 * 4) is that correct?

Comment: when i run it on Chrome here, each rotation is 4s (4000ms) long. if you want all 5 rotations to happen in a total of 4000ms, then do 800ms (4000 / 5).